# VLOOKUP/MATCH With Multiple Matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm at a loss for how to do something which I imagine one of you gurus has done before and shouldn't be too challenging. I have two sheets in my workbook (Let's call them ITEMS and LOCS).
Sheet ITEMS has a list of unique items in column A (roughly 10,000) and sheet LOCS has the items in column A and their locations in Column B. Now the issue arises since many items have multiple locations (up to five) and thus occupy multiple rows on the LOCS sheet. Is there a way to use some combination of VLOOKUP or MATCH in column B on my ITEMS sheet to get all the locations into one cell separated by a comma space. Obviously, if I put `=VLOOKUP($A:$A, LOCS!$A:$B,2,0)` into cell ITEMS!B1 it will only return the first location. Ideally, I would want it to display something like this: Shelf, Desk, Floor. Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated--thanks so much!

[Sample Data (Columns A:B from sheet ITEMS and columns D:E are from sheet LOCS and I highlighted the desired outcome in col B in green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52j0H.png)

Comment: Post some sample data and desired result.

Comment: I posted a little data for you all! Hope it helps make what I was asking more clear. I'm pretty new to VBA but am slowly getting the hang of it so if that's the best way to do it I would understand

Comment: I am also sure that this should be possible through PowerQuery as another option besides formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the new Dynamic Array Formulas you can use the following equation and drag down as needed:

Cell E2: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B14,A2:A14=D2))`

---

[image]

Comment: Haha good timing :-) I like the use of FILTER. From your experience, do you know if it will be faster than using a simple IF condition inside of TEXTJOIN? Edit - probably will be since it doesn't require an array formula.

Comment: I believe the `FILTER` will be faster since it most likely gets computed on the back end faster in comparison to a conditional statement like `IF`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to have access to `TEXTJOIN` and not have access to the `FILTER` function. Seems that having access to the new dynamic array formulas is not the norm right now

Comment: That's true - even now I'm on a computer that has access to TEXTJOIN but doesn't have FILTER yet. Cannot wait for all the new functions to be widely released, these will greatly improve the performance.

Comment: Awesome! This does the trick thanks so much, who would have thought that 365 license pays off

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @JustynaMK. Your solution will def apply to more people than mine given peoples lack of access to the new formulas. The new formulas are a **game changer** for sure. The `UNIQUE` function is my favorite so far

Comment: Just caught up on all these comments, it looks like I have access to Filter. It's a big dataset so Filter will definitely be the way to go.

Comment: Ahh cannot wait to start playing with these new beauties :-)

Comment: @urdearboy just curious, what does the True in the syntax do for me? Is it exact match like VLOOKUP?

Comment: @bgensits just type out the `TEXTJOIN` function and it will tell you. In this case, it means *ignore blanks*. So if you had a Item with no location, it wouldn't appear in the comma separated result.

Comment: @urdearboy Ah, it's amazing how many basic things I forgot in my month and a half being furloughed haha first day back. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Office 365** then you're in for a treat!

Here's my LOCS table -

[image]

And the array formula using `TEXTJOIN` (make sure to use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`) -

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(LOCS!$A$2:$A$10=A2,LOCS!$B$2:$B$10,""))`

The result -

[image]

Comment: WOW, beautiful. Infinitely easier than I imagined. I think I have a new favorite function. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem at all - I admit it's also one of my favourite functions! I'm also curious to see if you have access to FILTER as the second solution is potentially faster (I'm one of the users who unfortunately cannot use it yet).

Comment: I do have Filter (Office 365 on Mac). It flies through nearly 10,000 items with close to 45,000 locations. It is definitely a game-changer for my workflow

Comment: These functions are free to use on Excel Online in case you want to try them. It's how I do these things too (I unfortunately only have Excel 2019).

Comment: Oh that's super cool! Thanks for the tip @JvdV, I'll definitely give it a try.